# VBA Text Search If Exists

Tags: vba, excel, text

I'm using the below VBA to first find specific text and then select that cell, and then to find and replace text.  In both cases I want to allow for text that may not exist the worksheet, without causing an error.

What is the best way to find and select text strings AND find and replace text names only if it exists?

```
Sub test2()
'
' test2 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g

    Cells.Find(what:="STRING", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("G11").Select
    Cells.Find(what:="STRING", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("I13").Select
    Cells.Find(what:="STRING", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveCell.Replace what:="NAME", Replacement:="ALTERNATIVENAME", lookat:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Find(what:="NAME", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.Replace what:="NAME", Replacement:="ALTERNATIVENAME", lookat:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace all substrings named "example" by "newtext" on an entire spreadsheet I simply use the code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim rgn As Range        

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        LastCol = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set rgn = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    End With

    For Each cell In rgn
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = Replace(cell.Value, "example", "newtext")
    Next
End Sub
```

Please note that you have to replace "Sheet1" by the name of your spreadsheet. Also, the code will generate a runtime error if the spreadsheet is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at just replacing one text string with another throughout the sheet you could use:

```
Sub ReplaceString()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace _
        What:="STRING", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

End Sub
```

I think the reason you're getting errors is because you're trying to find a value and then select the cell with that value.  If not found it causes an error - this is what you need to check before selecting the cell.

This uses a variable to store the found range.  Before selecting the range, or do anything with the range a check is made to ensure the range is not nothing.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyFoundRange As Range

    Set MyFoundRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:="STRING", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not MyFoundRange Is Nothing Then
        MyFoundRange.Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test2()    
    With ActiveSheet '<--| or, if you want to specify a given sheet, use 'With Worksheets("MyGivenSheetName")'
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(1)).Replace What:="NAME", Replacement:="ALTERNATIVENAME", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False '<--| act on used cells only to avoid processing all column A cells 
    End With
End Sub
```